# How should I search information on the origin of a country on Google?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

I'm trying to find some information on how the very first *country* came into being. I'm not sure what keywords I should start with. I've tried synonyms like *state* and *nation* as well, but none of them works. From my vague memory, I guess this topic is related to history and sociology, but I don't know the correct English wording for it.

Comment: Are you looking for the etymology of _country_ in English, or are you looking for the origins of nationalism? The latter is probably off topic here.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I want to search the latter on Google, but I'm not sure what keywords to use. For example, what is the right term, country, nation, or state? What other keywords should I use? Should I use the word origin here or should I use something like come into being or come into existence?

Comment: I'd recommend starting here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalism – or here: [history.se] StackExchange.

Comment: Did you actually try the search phrase "first country"? It seems to me you need a specific definition of what you mean by country to get your answer, but if you're interested in the first country, your definition must be simple. You should study anthropology or ask some anthropology experts.

Comment: This question appears to be about the best way to code a Google search, not really a question about the English language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should look into the first *government*. This should lead to the discovery of the first nation or country, because they need governments. This should probably go into the history StackExchange site, though.